# @media doesn't work I cant understand why it is dont work

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]I tried a lot but noting work help pls. Just for text klsldkjslkfjslfjljdkljb mvbncfgvsdfs dfs srtsdfgxxb

```css
    .right_form {
        width: 300px;
        height: 350px;
        background-color: #fff;
        position:relative;
        margin-left: 300px;
        }
      @media (max-width: 1460px) {
    .right > .right_form {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

}
```

```html
   <div class="right" >
        <form action="POST" class="right_form">
            <label class="first_label">Try Your <span style="color:#FF8B38;">&nbsp;  FREE &nbsp;  </span> Trial Today</label>
            <section class="form_bars">
            <input type="text" class = "inputs" placeholder=" Name">
            <input type="email" class = "inputs" placeholder=" Email">
            <input type="password" class = "inputs" placeholder=" Password">
            <button type="submit" class = "form_button" >Get Started</button>
        </section>
        <!--End of section form_bars -->
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: in media must be margin-left (mistake)

Comment: If this solves your issue you can delete your question `:-)`

Comment: CSS doesn't support nested media query, so need to move out.
and change to `margin-left: 0`

Comment: @nghiepit He has tagged it as sass and sass supports it.

Comment: @Colder_Host you haven't asked us something.

Answer (score 0):

Media query is never applied because you're nesting `.right_form` into itself. See the generated output of your scss below.

```
.right_form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
@media (max-width: 1460px) {
  .right_form .right > .right_form {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry forgot about scobe